# A JavaScript Array class, same behavior, but that's not Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

For some reasons, I cannot create `class MyArray extends Array`, it breaks the constructor: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work.

They propose the `setPrototype` solution, but I have a lot of subclasses, and don't want to do that for every subclass.

So is there a class that behaves *exactly* like Array:

- can access elements via [index]
- is iterable
- has all builtin methods like .map, .filter etc.

but that's not Array itself? In this case I could just do `class MyArray extends ThatOtherArray`, and everything should be fine.

Comment: In a word - no.

Comment: As long as you don't need to transpile your code to something like ES5, going with `class MyArray extends Array` should be fine. The problem is the non-polyfillable, non-transpileable `new.target`.

Comment: The suggested workaround could be applied on `ThatOtherArray` which you'd then use to extend in all your subclasses as well.

Comment: @connexo no. However it would be possible to create an Array-like. But dont do this.

Comment: @Lux You're not giving arguments.

Comment: Just check the link in the question: "However, any subclass of FooError will have to manually set the prototype as well." so this won't help.